# Subdomain Root Displays Main Homepage in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, subdomain

I am developing a site on my local mac running Pow as a web server and have need to set up a subdomain. I've never done this in rails (or pow) before. I've set up my routes.rb according to what I've found in the RailsGuides but it points to my main homepage. Here is my routes.rb:

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root                              'static_pages#home'
  get     'profile/:login_id'       =>  'users#show', as: "profile"
  get     'login'                   =>  'sessions#new'
  post    'login'                   =>  'sessions#create'
  delete    'logout'                =>  'sessions#destroy'
  get     'soon'                    =>  'static_pages#coming_soon'

  resources :users

  namespace :admin do
      constraints subdomain: 'admin' do
        get '/'                     =>  'admin_pages#home', as: "admin_root"
        resources :roles
      end
    end

end
```

I want my main page at http://mysite.dev to point to static_pages#home and I want the admin subdomain at http://admin.mysite.dev to point to admin_pages#home. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar problem. Moving admin subdomain routes above root 'static_pages#home' solved it for me. It seems that GET '/' request just doesn't reach namespace :admin and stops at the root.